# Adapter constantly instanciating AdapterView

Tags: android, adapter

I've been following many tutorials on how to optimize such a list as a Gallery for example, but I cannot get my Adapter to re-cycle views.
Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("ImageAdapter","getView : "+convertView);
    ImageView imageView = null;

    if (convertView == null){
        //imageView = (ImageView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pic_adapter, null);
        imageView = new ImageView(context);


        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageView = imageView;

        imageView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        //imageView = holder.imageView;
    }

    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(plotsImages.get(position));
    Log.d("ImageAdapter","return : "+imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

In my logs I get "null" all the time at the beginning of getView, which means that convertView is not some re-cycled view, how is that?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Do you still see `"getView: null"` after scrolling? Also you don't need a ViewHolder for your current layout.

Comment: Do you have enough views to fill the screen +?  They are only recycled when you have enough for some to be out of view (thus available to be re-used).

Comment: Yes I have about 13 objects, and my view is large enough to display 3 at a time.
And I get the null all the time, after scrolling and scrolling ...

If you try on your computer what do you get ? No more null after a few scrolls?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the circular logic that you use in your ViewHolder is the culprit. When I tried to run your code the app crashed with an obscure error. However this works fine:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d("ImageAdapter","getView : "+convertView);
    ImageView imageView = null;

    if (convertView == null){
        //imageView = (ImageView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.pic_adapter, null);
        imageView = new ImageView(Example.this);
    } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
    }

    imageView.setImageDrawable(plotsImages.get(position));
    Log.d("ImageAdapter","return : "+imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

ViewHolders are supposed to save you from using `findViewById()` repeatedly to access child Views in the row layout. Since your layout is just an ImageView there is no need for a ViewHolder.

Comment: I've just tried this, and I keep getting null on the first log :/

Comment: When I instanciate ImageView i use the context given in the adapter constructor, is that correct?
 `public ImageAdapter(Activity context, List<Drawable> plotsImages) {
  Log.d("ImageAdapter", "CTOR");

  this.context = context;
  this.plotsImages = plotsImages;

  mInflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
 }`

Answer (score 0):

First get rid of the holder, what you get in convertView is what you return from getView(). That's what you expect in your code too, so why such unnecessary complexity?

What adapter class are you using? Can you try with BaseAdapter and make sure all overridden method returns appropriate data?

I'm thinking of the getItemViewType, if it returns a different value each time, recycling will be disabled.